# Combine SpringJPA and EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder. Repository returns empty data when Unit testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following  CrudRepository and Dao service. For testing purpose I am using EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(creating tables and inserting sample data).
In that case as you can see from the `RDBMSDaoImpl->test` method, when I try to access the data in PROPERTY table via SpringJPA it returns empty result.
But when I use the convertional way(jdbctemplate) I get value that inserted via insert-data.sql.

**Using Spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE.**

```
public interface OfPropertyRepository extends CrudRepository <OfProperty, String> {

   OfProperty findByName(String name);
}

@Service
public class RDBMSDaoImpl implements RDBMSDao {

   private static final String SQL = "SELECT VALUE FROM TIMS.PROPERTY WHERE ID=?";

   @Autowired 
   OfPropertyRepository OfPropertyRepository;

   @Override
   public int test() {

**//Return a value**
     String value =  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, String.class, "prop.key");   

**// no value found**
          OfPropertyRepository.findAll();
       }


   ////
   public class AppConfigTest {

   @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
   public DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
      return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)            
            .setName("TIMS")
            .addScript("classpath:/db/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:/db/insert-data.sql")
            .build();      
   }

   }

   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfigTest.class})
@ActiveProfiles("Test")
public class BaseSendServMessageRequestTest  implements ApplicationContextAware{}
```

Comment: Show your inserts for OfPropertyRepository

Comment: INSERT INTO TIMS.OFPROPERTY VALUES ('asd', 'P;A', 'IMOS');

Answer (score 0):

Adding missing bean described here
https://geowarin.github.io/using-spring-data-jpa-in-a-java-se-environment-and-run-tests-with-dbunit.html